# Hibernate One-To-Many JoinColumn with same name

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Entity(name = "Assignment")
class Assignment {
  @Id
  private int id;

  private String assignmentCode;

}

Entity(name = "Review")
class Review {
  @Id
  private int id;

  private String assignmentCode;
}
```

I have 2 tables each with 2 columns as above.
I want to create a list of reviews in the assignment entity and these reviews are joined on the column assignmentCode.

In the Assignment, I defined as below :

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Review.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="assignmentCode")
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
```

but when I retrieve Assignment like:

```
assignment = session.findById(Assignment.class, id);
```

I'm getting the exception:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name 'assignmentCode'

What's the correct to define the reviews collection?
I cannot change the table structures to have different column names.

Comment: What if you define @JoinColumn(name="assignmentCode", table="your_Review_tableName_here")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution for this is (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044726&start=0&sid=2e66d1aff1017f61f574f00e58836988)

```
@Entity(name = "Assignment")
class Assignment {
   @Id
   private int id;

   private String assignmentCode;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignment")
   private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();

   public void addReview(Review review) {
        reviews.add(review);
        reviews.setPost(this);
    }

    public void removeReview(Review review) {
        reviews.remove(review);
        reviews.setAssignment(null);
    }

}

@Entity(name = "Review")
class Review {
   @Id
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(
      name = "assignmentCode", 
      referencedColumnName = "assignmentCode"
   )
   private Assignment assignment;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should:

1. Add column annotation (@Column) before the Assignment.assignmentCode with name "assignmentCode" (and for other fields without this annotaion).
2. Add the Table annotation before your class entities.
3. Add the *table* statement into JoinColumn annotation.

The final code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assignment")
class Assignment {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name="assignment_code")
  private String assignmentCode;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Review.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="assignment_code", table="review")
  private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
class Review {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name="assignment_code")
  private String assignmentCode;
}
```

Comment: I'm working on an existing database, so I can't change the column names. So I used @Column(name="assignmentCode") and made these changes. But I'm getting the exception Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table

Comment: Then I need to see your existing db scheme to help you.
Or you can change names in annotations yourself (JoinColumn, Column, Table) according to your scheme.

Comment: Assignment Table:
Columns:
  ID ,
  AssignmentCode --- 

Review Table:
Columns:
  ID,
  AssignmentCode

Comment: Try to replace *reviews* field by: 

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Review.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="assignmentCode")
 private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();

Comment: Nope... That again gave the error Ambiguous column name 'assignmentCode'

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your error message, I believe it's because name of your column is different with your Java variable name, usually I will name my column on the database something like `assignment_code` and this column was references to join between Review and Assignment.

My first suggestion is, if my hunch correct about different naming between database column and Java variable,  put `@Column(name = "assignment_code")` above `private String assignmentCode`.

Second, I think you have a mistake when define `@OneToMany` relations. I will do something like this on `Assignment` class (I assume you want something like *Unidirectional* ,seeing from your code).

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="assignment_code")
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
```

Reminder, on `@JoinColumn` the name was the **references column** name on the database and **not Java variable name**.

Comment: Mine is an existing database. So I can't change the column names