# Java Hibernate JPA create an entity and Join two different tables referenced by the same column, with same column name

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue that want to resolve using just annotations, and not two different query to obtain the data. I need to join two different tables with the same column id. I have Travels, and at certain time, the rows in Travel are erased, but now TravelHistory (a table to save data) have the row with just the data needed to save (and with the same id of Travel... make sense). At certain time, Travel and TravelHistory may coexist.

I want to have the two different classes mapped by same id (`travel_id` is the name of column), something like this (code is simplified):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "travel_audit")
public class TravelAudit {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "travel_id")
    private Travel travel;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "travel_id")
    private TravelHistory travelHistory;

}
```

but Hibernate seems to not like that (having the same `name = "travel_id"`), so I have errors to create the Bean.

For this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646091/3669309) I put a little more effort, and all detail, so to have more references to the tables:

```
@Column(name = "travel_id")
private Long travelId;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Travel.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "travel_id", table = "travel")
private Travel travel;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = TravelHistory.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "travel_id", table = "travel_history")
private TravelHistory travelHistory;
```

But it didn't work.

After that I want to make an `Optional<TravelAudit> findByTravelId(Long travelId);` and obtain Travel and/or TravelHistory

How can I do this? Unfortunately I think I'm going to have to retrieve the travel_id (it's a Long) and get the other tables separately.

The error is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: Usually you don't write "getByTravelId" but "getByTravel" (at least with springs JpaRepository) and put either a long or your whole entity as the parameter. However you can also write a query on your own like this (with the @Query annotation): `SELECT ta FROM TravenAudit ta WHERE ta.travel.id = :travel_id`

Comment: Your issue with the Join columns seems like you misunderstand the join column annotation, and the answer you've linked. The 'name' is used to define the foreign key within the current table, so you are defining two reference mappings to use the same column - this is a problem as Entities are writeable, and JPA needs to know which 'one' controls setting the value. You have to mark one as read-only (insertable+updatable=false) for it to accept both mappings using the same column. I don't now why you'd have a table definition in there, it knows the table referenced from the entity referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping for your audit Entity might be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "travel_audit")
public class TravelAudit {
    @Id
    @Column(name="travel_id")
    private String travelId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "travel_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Travel travel;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "travel_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TravelHistory travelHistory;
}
```

If you are using JPA/Hibernate to generate the DDL, you'll want to make sure there isn't a constraint generated for the travel_audit.travel_id -> travel table reference, as it will get broken any time your app tries to delete travel rows still referenced by a travel audit instance.

Having a basic mapping (travelId) will allow you to query using the value without having to join between the two tables and complicate your queries as the default inner join would break the logic you need.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer. This works. Makes sense, I didn't think about insertable and updatable false... Yes, in the meantime I just made a basic mapping with travelId, and then search for the other two separately... and in update, that value always have to exists. I think is safer... so I'm going to leave it like this. Thank you again!